Unable to call a production API using a proxy server in Next.js
I'm trying to integrate an API for package shipments in a Next.js application. The API has almost no documentation
Both endpoints work perfectly when tested in Postman, but I can't make the production one work in my frontend code since it's giving me cors errors so I've created a proxy server using the http-proxy-middleware package in a Next.js API route. This proxy server works well with the test API domain, but when I try to use it with the production API I'm getting a 504 Gateway Timeout error, and the proxy server is returning the message "Error occurred while trying to proxy: localhost:3000/".
I've double-checked the proxy configuration a thousand times, and it seems to be correct, as it works with the test API domain. I'm not sure what else I can try to make the proxy work with the production API.
The endpoints I found are
PROD:
https://www.cexpr.es/wspsc/apiRestGrabacionEnviok8s/json/grabacionEnvio.
TEST:
https://www.test.cexpr.es/wspsc/apiRestGrabacionEnviok8s/json/grabacionEnvio
My code that is working with the api test but no the prod one
// pages/api/\[...slug\].js
import { createProxyMiddleware, fixRequestBody } from 'http-proxy-middleware';

export const config = { api: { externalResolver: true, bodyParser: false, }, };

const apiProxy = createProxyMiddleware({
target: "https://www.cexpr.es/wspsc/apiRestGrabacionEnviok8s/json/grabacionEnvio",
changeOrigin: true,
pathRewrite: { \[`^/api/proxy`\]: '' },
onProxyReq: fixRequestBody,
});

export default function (req, res) {
apiProxy(req, res, (result) =\> {
if (result instanceof Error) {
throw result;
}
throw new Error(`Request '${req.url}' is not proxied! We should never reach here!`);
    });
};

Expected behavior: When calling the proxy server endpoint (/api/proxy), I expect the request to be successfully forwarded to the production API endpoint, and the response to be returned to the client
